# Android Grid View with sections Headers

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-listview, android-gridview

I am planning to two different kinds of lists in the same Grid View. Basically, for example, say a list of cars and a list of bikes.

I want to display both of them in the same Grid View.

I also want to display headers before the cars list and even before the bikes list. I want something as shown below.

[image]

***I am aware of many such posts existing in the web as well as StackOverflow but none of them answer my question. Some of then point towards sticky header library and some of them suggest converting the elements to headers which would again require complex position management which I would not be able to.***

Any suggestion or help would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I think the solution is simple. Create RecyclerView and use Grid Layout. Create an adapter and inside it use two types of items. Use method spanSizeLookup, override getSpanSize() function and set size for Section (1) and size for your other items. That's it.

Kotlin code for spanSizeLookup:

```
val layoutManager = (recyclerView.layoutManager as GridLayoutManager)
    layoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : SpanSizeLookup() {
        override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
        return if (adapter.getItem((position) is Section) layoutManager.spanCount else 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It leads into scroll performance lagging

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom adapter class which has custom listener interface, and you can
detect if button has clicked through this listener.

```
public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private YourCustomListener listener;

    private List<Object> yourObjects;

    private Context mContext;

    public YourAdapter(final Context context, final YourCustomListener listener, final List<Object> yourObjects) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.yourObjects = yourObjects;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return yourObjects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(final int position) {
        return yourObjects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        Button button;
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }
        final Object obj = getItem(position);

        button = view.findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonid);

        if (listener != null) {
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {
                    listener.onButtonOnItemClicked(obj);
                }
            });
        }

        return view;

    }

    public void setListener(YourCustomListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface YourCustomListener {

        void onButtonOnItemClicked(Object obj);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It solved my problem. of the Onclick Listener But Sorry as I had to accept @Jimale Abdi answer as that tells how to achieve section header. Thanks once again.

Comment: You can achieve by getting the spanCount